# meteor-shopify : expected String to be a Hash

Tags: javascript, meteor, shopify

I'm using [froatsnook:shopify](https://github.com/froatsnook/meteor-shopify) trying to modify a custom collection's metafields.

**Server JS**

```
/**
 * Modify Shopify Custom Collection Metafields
 * @request PUT /admin/custom_collections/#{id}.json
 * 
 * @param  {Number}   collection_id 
 * @param  {Object}   collection_data
 * @param  {Function} callback
 */
modifyShopifyCustomCollectionMetafields: function(collection_id, collection_data, callback) {

  var meta = ShopifyAPI.modifyCustomCollection({
    id: collection_id,
    custom_collection : JSON.stringify( collection_data )
  })

  if ( AdminConfig.debug.server ) console.log( 'modifyShopifyCustomCollectionMetafields', meta )

  if ( callback ) callback( meta )

  return meta;

},
```

**Client JS**

```
Meteor.call('modifyShopifyCustomCollectionMetafields', collection_id, {
  'id': collection_id,
  'metafields' : [
  {
    'key' : 'color_primary',
    'value' : design_settings.colors.primary,
    'value_type' : 'string',
    'namespace' : 'store',
  },
  {
    'key' : 'color_dark',
    'value' : design_settings.colors.primary_dark,
    'value_type' : 'string',
    'namespace' : 'store',
  },
  {
    'key' : 'color_light',
    'value' : design_settings.colors.primary_light,
    'value_type' : 'string',
    'namespace' : 'store',
  },
  ]
}, function (data) {
  console.log( 'Clientside callback', data )
})
```

All looks fine to be, but then I get this in the (server) console:

```
PUT https://<MY_STORE_NAME>.myshopify.com/admin/custom_collections/42393729.json?custom_collection={"id":"42393729","metafields":[{"key":"color_primary","value":"#5c28a4","value_type":"string","namespace":"store"},{"key":"color_dark","value":"#401a74","value_type":"string","namespace":"store"},{"key":"color_light","value":"#a42da8","value_type":"string","namespace":"store"}]}
```

**Exception while invoking method 'modifyShopifyCustomCollectionMetafields' Error: failed [400] {"errors":{"custom_collection":"expected String to be a Hash"}}**

Note that if I remove `JSON.stringify(...)` from the serverside JS, it will try to send `[Object object]` in the request URI.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See comment on @ilrein question for details.

Appears to be an issue with package itself.

Here is a simple client API (for private apps with basic auth) I made to circumvent the issue: [Github gist](https://gist.github.com/elzii/4c7061c843e02ac5bbdb)

Answer (score 5):

I think there *may* be a bug in the package. Have you successfully used the API to POST before? I'm not sure if the issue is in scope for all POST requests, or for only some (using the awesome froatsnook package).

I've made an [issue](https://github.com/froatsnook/meteor-shopify/issues/3) where I too, faced a POST request that returned "string expects to be a hash".

I'm temporarily sidestepping this issue by using plain old HTTP.Post and passing in an object with what the Shopify API specifically asks for:

```
var options = {
  data: params,
  headers: {
    'X-Shopify-Access-Token': Meteor.user().profile.shopifyAccessToken
  }
};

var newScript = HTTP.post("https://" + Meteor.user().profile.shopName + ".myshopify.com/admin/script_tags.json" , options);
```

Comment: Yeah, I cant seem the contact the author of the package. I don't know why he opts to send all the data as `form-urlencoded` rather than just RAW body request. That's where the errors are coming from. It works fine when the URL params are fairly simple, but it gets messy when you have nested objects and arrays. The url encoded version becomes `custom_collection['metafield'][0]['value']='some value'` and then you're dealing with shopify's parsing of the encoded uri.

I ended up just building my own client API to talk to shopify. A fork of his that sent params in body would be great but oh well

Comment: Heer's a gist of the API for anyone that wants it https://gist.github.com/elzii/4c7061c843e02ac5bbdb